# MSStream - what's the point?

Tags: stream, winjs

Bear with me on this one please.

When setting response of a WinJS.xhr response I can set it to, among other things, to 'ms-stream' or blob. I was hoping to leverage the stream concept when downloading a file in such a way that I don't have to keep the whole response in memory (video files can be huge).

However, all I can do with 'ms-stream' object is read it with an MSStreamReader. This would be great if I could say to it 'consume 1024 bytes from the stream, and 'loop' this, until stream is exhausted. However from reading the docs (haven't tried this, so correct me if I'm wrong), it appears I can only read from the stream once (e.g. readAsBlob method) and I can't set the start position. This means I need to read the whole response into memory as a blob. Which I can achieve with responseType set to 'blob' in the first place. So what is the point of MSStream anyway?

Comment: I noticed one difference is that the progress event gets fired multiple times for 'ms-stream' responses, and either once or even never (WinJS 2.0 specific?) for 'arraybuffer' responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post a while back to help answer questions about MSStream and other oddball object types that you encounter in WinRT and the host for JavaScript apps. See http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/03/22/msstream-blob-objects-html5/. Yes, you can use MSStreamReader to for some work (it's a synchronous API), but you can also pass an MSStream to URL.createObjectURL to assign it to an img.src and so forth.

With MSStream, here's some of what I wrote: "MSStream is technically an extension of this HTML5 File API that provides interop with WinRT. When you get MSStream (or Blob) objects from some HTML5 API (like an XmlHttpRequest with responseType of “ms-stream,” as you’d use when downloading a file or video, or from the canvas’ msToBlob method), you can pass those results to various WinRT APIs that accept IInputStream or IRandomAccessStream as input. To use the canvas example, the msRandomAccessStream in a blob from msToBlob can be fed into APIs in Windows.Graphics.Imaging for transform or transcoding. A video stream can be similarly worked with using the APIs in Windows.Media.Transcoding. You might also just want to write the contents of a stream to a StorageFile (that isn’t necessarily on the file system) or copy them to a buffer for encryption."

So MSStreamReader isn't the end-all. The real use of MSStream is to pass the object into WinRT APIs that accept the aforementioned interface types, which opens many possibilities.

Admittedly, this is an under-documented area, which is exactly why I wrote my series of posts under the title, Q&A on Files, Streams, Buffers, and Blobs (the initial post is on http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/03/18/why-doesnt-storagefile-close-method/).

Comment: Yes. Your series of articles is on top of any search containing a combination of winjs stream winrt etc. I can't stress enough how helpful it was. It is probably the only place that documents the usage and purpose of some of these objects. Still, I was unclear on what actually "detaching a stream" means, and thought that MSStream is closed, download is canceled, and data up to that point is available in IInputStream. Obviously this was wrong, and in a manner of speaking IInputStream lies below MSStream. Once more, thanks for the articles, they (along with some others) have been invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out that the method `msDetachStream` gives access to underlying stream and doesn't interrupt the download process. I initially thought that any data that was not downloaded was lost when calling this since the docs mention that `MSStream` object is closed.